# How to concatenate a character constant into a string. C

Tags: c, string

If I have a constant character defined in C, can I concatinate it into a string literal?

```
#ifdef WIN32
#  define SEP '\\'
#  define ALTSEP '/'
#else
#  define SEP '/'
#  define ALTSEP '\\'
#endif

#define SOME_STRING_LITERAL "foo"

/* code snippet */
/* Desired string: "prefix_foo/bar" */
const char *path = "prefix_" SOME_STRING_LITERAL SEP "bar";
```

Of course this fails, because `SEP` is not defined as a string literal, but is there some way to make `SEP` concatenate correctly? or would I need another define, such as `#define SEP_STR "/"`.

Comment: No, you cannot turn a character literal into a string literal.

Comment: Well it worked for me for `/` forward slash, without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in C.

The core problem is that the `"` symbol is something so fundamental that it gets interpreted even before the pre-processor knows what it should regard as pre-processing tokens or not.

Stringinizing with the # operator won't help. Even if you write a macro like

```
#define STRINGINIZE(x) #x
#define CHAR_TO_STR(ch) STRINGINIZE(ch)
```

and then invoke it as

```
const char *path = "prefix_" SOME_STRING_LITERAL CHAR_TO_STR(SEP) "bar";
```

it will do you no good, because you'll end up with a string like

```
prefix_foo`\`bar
```

Also you cannot do this:

```
const char *path = "prefix_" SOME_STRING_LITERAL CHAR_TO_STR(SEP)[1] "bar";
```

because it is identical to what we had in the first place and it won't compile.

Also you cannot make a solution based on concatenating pre-processor tokens, because `"` is a more fundamental symbol than `##`.

So the only solution seems to be to declare the characters as a string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compile-time Stringizing operator `#`

`#define SEP_STR(x) #x`
`#define SEP_STR_2(x) SEP_STR(x)`

`const char *path = "prefix_" SOME_STRING_LITERAL SEP_STR_2(SEP) "bar";`

or you can define `SEP` as `"\\"`.

Double level of MACRO Expansion is required due to the reason explained well in [this link](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC17)

In short:

> If you want to stringify the result of expansion of a macro argument, you have to use two levels of macros.

Comment: `SEP_STR(SEP)` gets converted to The literal "SEP"

Comment: The solution is an extra layer of redirection.

Comment: Won't you get `"'/'"` then?

Comment: It would be nice if it were possible, you could have a generic macro `STRINGIFY_CHAR` so any char could be made into a string constant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining SEP as a character, define it as a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SEP "\\"
#define SOME_STRING_LITERAL "foo"
int main() {
    const char * path = "prefix_" SOME_STRING_LITERAL SEP "bar";
    puts(path);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `prefix_foo\bar`